# Use a Wireless N adapter with MIMO to connect to multiple networks

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, adapter

I have a Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 AGN wireless adapter. According to wikipedia it has 2 antennas. I was wondering if it is possible to connecto two wireless networks simultaneously under Windows 7.

In Linux, with the iwconfig commands it is possible to split an adapter into two and access two networks at the same time. (Or so I think).

Am I asking for the impossible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported in Windows 7, but I'm having trouble finding good documentation on the feature. I do remember that it usually means dipping into the console to set up.  Here's a link that discusses part of it:

http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/14593-microsoft-virtual-wifi-miniport-adapter.html

The virtual adapter mentioned here is normally used as a virtual access point, but it can be set up as an additional normal wireless network adapter to connect to multiple networks.

What it will not do (and what your linux setup isn't really doing either) is devote one of your MIMO antennas to each network, but rather it will split time from both antennas to both networks.